# MyComponent outside AppComponent in Angular2 + .Net MVC

Tags: angular

I have a SPA web application based on Angular2 (v5) and ASP.Net.

Everything is fine in the default Angualar "app" component.

The problem is that I want to run an "admin" page outside the AppComponent.
Basically to not have the nav-menu plus router-outlet and because I want to add some scripts and other different stuff without touching the existent components/logic.

I created the AdminComponent and I can render (ASP.Net) a Index.cshtml page that contain the component but the component is not rendered.
It works well if I use it inside the "app" component.

I tried to add the AdminComponent in the AppModule and bootstrap it without success.

Is it possible?

Comment: why run the admin page outside? You should be able to do that. Are you trying to restrict access to that component to only admins?

Comment: in angular 6 you can use angular elements to export the component as custom html tag to be used outside the root component.

Comment: (update question) I want to run the "admin" component out of the app because I don't want the nav menu (and router outlet) in that page